# Under what conditions do these two SQL queries give different results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Disclaimer: I'm helping a person learn SQL by using an online tutorial. So you can consider this as a homework question.

There are 3 SQL Server tables that we are dealing with here:

- Ships (name, class)
- Classes - different classes of the ship (class)
- Outcomes - what has happened to that ship (ship, result)

Now there are several crazy things in the layout of the database, the biggest one being that the ships in the `Outcomes` table may not be present in the `Ships` table when they are named the same way as the class in `Class`.

The point is to get the number of sunk ships of each class. I have helped the student to get to the following SQL:

```
Select 
    dbo.Classes.[class], Count(dbo.Outcomes.ship) as [count] 
from
    dbo.Classes
left join 
    dbo.Ships on dbo.Ships.[class] = dbo.Classes.[class]
left join 
    dbo.Outcomes on (dbo.Outcomes.ship = dbo.Classes.[class] or 
                     dbo.Outcomes.ship = dbo.Ships.name)
                 and dbo.Outcomes.result = 'sunk'
Group by 
    dbo.Classes.[class]
```

However, it, apparently, is the incorrect solution, as it can on some occasions return incorrect results. On the web i have managed to find the following solution to this tutorial:

```
select 
    classes.class, count(T.ship) 
from 
    classes
left join
    (select 
         ship, class 
     from 
         outcomes
     left join 
         ships on ship = name 
     where 
         result = 'sunk'
     union
     select 
         ship, class 
     from 
         outcomes
     left join 
         classes on ship = class 
     where 
         result = 'sunk') as T on classes.class = T.class
group by 
    classes.class
```

But I cannot understand under which conditions will the results be different. Doesn't the `Union` operation of using two different join paths serve the exactly same function as does `OR` in the condition of the join?

P.S. This particular question in the tutorial is actually marked as 2 on the scale from 1-5 for difficulty. So i feel myself quite stupid.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the 3 tables?  BTW -- odd data (exists, not exists, 'special secrete codes' stuffed in fields) is the *norm*, not craziness.  You should see what it looks like inside corporate database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this dataset:

```
with Ships as (
    select * from (values
         ('HMS Prince of Wales','King George V')
        ,('King George V','King George V')
    )Ships(name,class)
),
Classes as (
    select * from (values
         ('King George V')
    )Classes(class)
),
Outcomes as (
    select * from (values
         ('HMS Prince of Wales','sunk')
        ,('King George V','sunk')
    )Outcomes(ship,result)
)
```

the two queries you provide respectively yield:

```
class         count
------------- -----------
King George V 3

class         
------------- -----------
King George V 2
```

The reason for the difference is that *UNION* is a set operator that eliminates duplicates (unlike *UNION ALL*) while the *OR* operator doesn't. We can test this by replacing UNION in the second query with UNION ALL, which now yields:

```
class         
------------- -----------
King George V 3
```

just as in your first proposed solution.

Answer (score 3):

The queries might return different results in many cases.  One obvious case is when a sunk ship matches both `class` and `name` in `outcomes`.  The `union` in the second query will return one row in this case.  The `join` in the first query will return two rows.  Hence the counts will be different.

I think you could fix this particular issue by using `count(distinct)` in the first query.

Answer (score 1):

Needed goal :
"The point is to get the number of sunk ships of each class. I have helped the student to get to the following SQL:"

Sudo code should be  created in three steps. You would need to break them into working steps

```
select * from class 
//create a list of all of the classes that exists in your db

select * from [working previous statement] where results = "sunk"
//create another select statement that uses the previous select statement to refine  results
//then refine it to have ships that have been sunk

select count from [[previous statement with the two selects]]
//This create the count of all of the sunk ships.

select count from [[previous statement with the two selects]] group by [previous statement with one select]
//this one should create the individual count of all of the sunken ships based on it's class

select sum from [[your pick of which statement]]
//do a sum
```

naturally you will need to do the linking so the code should be implemented as
select ship from ships sh, classes cl, outcome oc where sh.class = cl.class and oc.ship = sh.ship and oc.result = sunk group by cl.classes

then add the count steps in the mix.